# Why do I appear to be from "Unknown" country?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, exit-relays

I configured my ExitNodes for {US}, However when I track the links I visit using Tor it shows that I'm surfing from an "Unknown" country, what could the problem be?

Comment: It is NOT recommended to set this option and restrict your exit nodes to one place. The number of exit nodes are limited and setting this option would just throw your anonymity out of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Tor uses the Maxmind GeoIP database for look ups to determine the country of origin for a given IP. If an IP is looked up in the database that is either completely unlisted, or has a listed IP but it cannot find a record of its country, it returns "xx" for the country code. Therefore "Unknown"

When Tor fails to find an exit node with an exit policy matching your request in the requested country, it will fail-over to use other countries instead so that it doesn't disrupt your usage. If you want to stop this from happening, choose strict mode in torrc.

```
StrictExitNodes 1
ExitNodes {us}
```

Also, it *shouldn't* matter but normally the country code is lowercase.